# the value not be change by mongoose's population?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema, the follows is a variable in it:

```
receiveComments:[{
    whoComment:{
      type:ObjectId,
      ref:'Student'
    },
    whichHelp:{
      type:ObjectId,
      ref:"Help"
    },
    whichComment:{
      type:ObjectId,
      ref:"Comment"
    }
  }],
```

one of variable `whichComment` is relative about the `Comment` schema,the `Comment` schema has a variable like this:

```
have_saw: {
    type:Boolean,
    default:false
},
```

when I change the `have_saw` to true by modify `whichComment` population, after that, I saved.
but when I get the `have_saw` value, it is still false, so it indicate I have not success to change the `have_saw` value.
so, what's going on?

```
Student
      .findOne({_id:id})
      .populate('receiveComments.whoComment receiveComments.whichHelp receiveComments.whichComment sendHelps.whichHelp sendHelps.helpers.info')
      .exec((err,student)=>{
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
```

Comment: Can you put your code, how are you doing populate?

Comment: yes right now,wait a sec

Comment: I add that in my question above.

Comment: You should modify have_saw not by using populate of whichComment, but using Comment model.

Comment: where are you updating your `have_saw` field? Can you show that part of your code?